# How do we prove that compact spaces in metric spaces are bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, solution-verification, complete-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. Then $(X,d)$ is both complete and bounded.

**My solution**

The space $(X,d)$ is indeed complete. This is because every Cauchy sequence which admits a convergent subsequence is also convergent.

Now it remains to prove the bounded part.

Let us suppose otherwise that $X$ is unbounded.

Thus for every $r > 0$ there is an element $x\in X$ such that $x\not\in B(x_{0},r)$.

In particular, if we choose $r = n$, there corresponds $x_{n}\in X$ such that $d(x_{n},x_{0}) \geq n$.

But, since $x_{n}$ admits a subsequence $x_{f(n)}$ which converges, such subsequence is bounded: $d(x_{f(n)},x_{0}) < N$ for some natural $N$.

Thus if we choose $n_{0} = N + 1$ and noticing that $f(n_{0}) \geq n_{0}$, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
N+1 = n_{0} \leq f(n_{0}) \leq d(x_{f(n_{0})},x_{0}) \leq N
\end{align*}
which is a contradiction. Therefore $X$ is bounded.

Could someone please point out any theoretical flaw, if there is one?

Comment: You can also argue using the "every open cover has a finite subcover" characterization of compact sets. Let $x_0$ be any point in $X$ (assuming $X$ is nonempty). Then the collection $\{B_r(x_0) : r > 0\}$ of open balls of radius $r$ centered at $x_0$ is an open cover of $X$, hence it has a finite subcover $\{B_{r_1}(x_0),\ldots,B_{r_n}(x_0)\}$. Then if $R = \max\{r_1,\ldots,r_n\}$ we have that $X$ is contained in $B_R(x_0)$, hence is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subsequence converges to some point $y_0$ and we get $d(x_{f(n)},y_0) <N$ instead of $d(x_{f(n)},x_0) <N$. (Though $d(x_{f(n)},x_0) $ is also bounded you have give some argument to justify this).